# Receiving an image using Python 3 Sockets

Tags: image, sockets, python-3.x

I'm having a bit of a hard time receiving an image using sockets. I think the problem is related to the fact that sockets send both a header and the actual image, and that the two need different decoding.

This is the code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))

mysock.send(
    'GET http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode('utf-8'))
count = 0
fhand = open("stuff.jpg", "wb")
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    fhand.write(data)
mysock.close()
fhand.close()
```

Comment: Do you **have** to use sockets?

Comment: Yes. I know the urllib.request way: `from urllib.request import urlopen
img = urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg').read()
fhand = open('cover.jpg', 'wb')
fhand.write(img)
fhand.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a header.  The end of it is after the first \r\n\r\n sequence.  Once you see that sequence send the rest to a file.  Here's a crude fix:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as mysock:
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
    mysock.send(b'GET http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n')
    header = b''
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if not data:
            raise RuntimeError('no header?')
        header += data
        # end-of-header in buffer yet?
        eoh = header.find(b'\r\n\r\n')
        if eoh != -1:
            break
    # split the header off and keep data read after it.
    header,data = header[:eoh+4],header[eoh+4:]
    print(header.decode())
    with open("stuff.jpg", "wb") as fhand:
        fhand.write(data)
        while True:
            data = mysock.recv(512)
            if not data:
                break
            fhand.write(data)
```

Here's the header.  Note that the content length is in the header, so if you were to send an HTTP request with a keepalive, you would have to read exactly that many bytes after the header.  since `Connection: close` is specified, you only have to read until no more data is received.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 22 May 2016 23:22:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 19:05:04 GMT
ETag: "b294001f-111a9-526172f5b7cc9"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 70057
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```